# Obj-C get JSON key name

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Hi I am trying to create a link between PHP and iOS, and I am using JSON. Although my JSON array is strange, I am not the creator, as this is in a closed API, I cannot change it.

The JSON looks like this:

```
{"success":true,"errors":[],"data":{"Servers":{"6":"Name here"}}}
```

The 6 is the ID of the server, and the other one is the name.

As you can see the key is the ID and the value is the name, but how do I get the ID in Objective-C? I know how to receive the server name, but to do that I need to find the server ID.

Here is my current code:

```
NSDictionary *json = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    NSError *error;
    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
 NSDictionary *test = [dataDict objectForKey:@"Servers"]
            NSLog(@"%@", [test objectForKey:@"6"]); // Server Name (ID of server is 6)
```

`_responseData` is just the JSON data received from the PHP script.

Comment: Where are you at so far? Show the code. Can you get the dictionary?

Comment: Your "Servers"-key is nested in the "data"-key, so you have to call objectForKey:@"data" first and then on that result again with "Servers". Checkout Zaph's answer. His jsonDict is your _responseData.

Comment: If all else fails, read the documentation for NSDictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do something like:

```
[test enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString* serverId, NSString *serverName, BOOL *stop) {
    // Process data here.
}];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = @{@"success":@"true",
                           @"errors":@[],
                           @"data":@{
                               @"Servers":@{
                                   @"6":@"Name here"
                                   }
                               }
                           };

NSDictionary *servers = jsonDict[@"data"][@"Servers"];
NSString *serverID = [[servers allKeys] firstObject];
NSLog(@"serverID: %@", serverID);
```

Output:

> serverID: 6

For more than one server:

```
for (NSString *serverId in servers) {
    NSString *serverName = servers[serverId];
    NSLog(@"server key: %@, serverId: %@", serverId, serverName);
}
```

Or using an enumeration:

```
[servers enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString* serverId, NSString *serverName, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"server serverId: %@, serverName: %@", serverId, serverName);
}];
```

Comment: Although this gets the answer, I feel it avoids the point of the question. It isn't worded all that well, but it's obvious that he's going to need to handle *each* server, not just the first.

Comment: Added a lop for handling all keys.

Answer (score 0):

This would be represented with a dictionary in Objective-C, so you would want to do something like below. I'm assuming you're storing the server's response in a variable named `myServerResponse` which is a dictionary.

```
NSDictionary *data = myServerResponse[@"data"];
NSDictionary *server = data[@"Servers"];
for (NSString *key in server) {
        NSString *serverId = key;
        NSString *serverName = server[key];
}
```

EDIT: Made `data` and `server` dictionary.
Edit Zaph: added `@` prefix to key  strings, corrected @"Servers"

Comment: That's what happens when you pseudo code quickly! Thanks for catching this.