# How to get the key values from NSDictionary in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a Dictionary:

```
@{
  @"FirstName" : @"Katie",
  @"SecondName" : @"Brown"
}
```

How do I get the keys "FirstName" and "SecondName" from the above dictionary.

Comment: [Get all keys of an NSDictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057063/get-all-keys-of-an-nsdictionary-as-an-nsarray)

Comment: Doesn't appear as a valid JSON

Comment: if ([dict objectForKey:@"Firstname"] != nil) { // key not null }

Comment: can use NSArray *arrKey = [dict allKeys];
              NSArray *arrVal = [dict allValues];

Comment: @Shubhank I did not found answer from google

Comment: @all what is the reason for the downvotes ????!!!

Comment: @gurmandeep now is it a valid json

Comment: Yes it is a valid JSON now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obj-C get JSON key name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636072/obj-c-get-json-key-name)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all keys of an NSDictionary as an NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057063/get-all-keys-of-an-nsdictionary-as-an-nsarray)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
NSData* yourJSONData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:yourJSONData options:0 error:nil];
NSArray *allTheKeys = [jsonObject allKeys];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get as

```
if ([yourDictname objectForKey:@"FirstName"] && [yourDictname objectForKey:@"SecondName"]) {
    // key exists.
}
else
{
    // ...
}
```

or you can get

```
if ([[yourDictname allKeys] containsObject:@"FirstName"] && [[yourDictname allKeys] containsObject:@"SecondName"]) {
    // key exists.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get array of keys from dictionary like,

```
   NSDictionary *dic; // your dictionary here

NSArray *allKeys = [dic allKeys];
NSLog(@"all keys : %@",allKeys);
```

You can got same for value also like `[dic allValues]`

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *jsonString = @" {\"FirstName\" : \"Katie\",\"SecondName\" : \"Brown\"}";
NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
for (NSString *key in dic.allKeys) {
    NSLog(@"key: %@ value: %@", key, dic[key]);
}
```

or try [JSONModel](https://github.com/jsonmodel/jsonmodel).

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer